# Refresh dropdownlist based on select option in list

Tags: jquery

I really need help. Am new to `jQuery` and i am trying to refresh a `dropdown list` or change its value when an option from the list is selected.

**HTML**

```
<select name="State_locate" class="State">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">Select a state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
<div id="City_1" class="Alabama">
    <select name="City_location[]" class="CityExt">
        <option value="Null" selected="selected">Select a city</option>
        <option value="Avondale">Avondale</option>
        <option value="Buckeye">Buckeye</option>
        <option value="Catalina">Catalina</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="City_1" class="Alaska">
    <select name="City_location[]" class="CityExt">
        <option value="Null" selected="selected">Select a city</option>
        <option value="Lancaster">Lancaster</option>
        <option value="Soth">Soth</option>
        <option value="Foothills">Foothills</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// JavaScript Document

$("select").bind("change", function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "AL") {
        $(".Alabama").slideDown();

        $(".Alaska").slideUp(function () {

            if ($('.Alabama').is(':visible')) {
                $(".Alaska option[value='Lancaster']").attr('selected', 'selected')
            }
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == "AK") {
        $(".Alaska").slideDown();
        $(".Alabama").slideUp();
    }
})
```

what i am trying to do is when a state is selected , then a city drops down. That works perfectly. But once submitted, the values of the city are stored in the array `City_location[]`.

The problem am having is that if the user selects a city for Alaska and later on selects another city under Alabama before submitting the form, you end up with two cities under Alabama and Alaska in the array.

I am looking for a way to select the value "Null" for the state Alaska if Alabama is selected. But the code i have does not work. It works only if the value is anything else but "Null". For example if i use the value "Lancaster", in this section of the `jQuery` code

```
$(".Alaska option[value='Lancaster']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

It only works once. If i do it twice, it does not update. How can i solve this problem.

Sorry for the long code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why would you store it in an array?Are you selecting multiple values??

Comment: I am storing it in an array because if i dont do it like that, when i submit my form i am not able to retrieve a city because the select has the same name. This is just a sample code, i am trying to do this for all 50 states. If i had them with different names, then my code will be longer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.state').on('change',function() {
   $('.CityExt').val('');
}
```

Then whenever the state select is changed, it'll set the value of both city selects to nothing.

Comment: i tried your suggestion  but did not have any success with it. i used some your idea as well as the one above to come up with this code.                                                                   if ($(this).val() == "AL") {
        $(".Alabama").slideDown();
   
        $(".Alaska").slideUp(function() {

    if ($(".Alabama:visible").length){
    $(".Alaska                                                      option[value='Anchoragege']").attr('selected',               'selected');
                              }

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(".Alaska option:eq(0)").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

Since the null element is the first one this will resolve your concern.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried your suggestion and nothing happened.

Comment: I think the above solution is what your looking for.It selects `null` value for class `.alaska` when you select `.Alabama`.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem. Instead of using "prop" i used "attr"

```
$(".Alaska option[value='Lancaster']").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Now every time when another city is selected before submitting more than twice, the code does not only work one time.

I looked up the meanings but dont still understand it quite well, why to use "prop" instead "attr" in jquery. I'll keep doing search. I appreciate all the help i got from all the people who responded to me.

Comment: It is because you are using jquery 1.6+ and prop is introduced in this have a look more about it on prop with http://api.jquery.com/prop/